# How to add buttons to a pdf using jspdf?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jspdf

I am redering a pdf from html using the [jspdf plugin](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), the plugin works by allowing you to add text and images straight into the pdf or by using the `fromHTML` function which converts the html into pdf, however, it leaves behind the buttons.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML(
     $('.element').get(0),
     10,
     10, {
         'width': 170, // max width of content on PDF
         'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
     },
 function (dispose) {
     doc.save('Test.pdf');
 });
```

In the html, I have radio buttons that do not show up in the pdf

```
<div class="col-sm-12 element">
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio1" ng-model="radio1" value="1">radio value 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="radio2" ng-model="radio2" value="2">radio value 2</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So where is the HTML for the buttons and the `.element` element you're getting ?

Comment: I just added the element class to the outer div here to show that this is the mark-up that I'm using

Comment: Did you try `doc.fromHTML( $('.element').html(), 10, 10 ...` as it should accept a HTML string as well ?